# Discord.Net Client.Guilds List is always empty

Tags: c#, discord, discord.net

I've used multiple methods to get the SocketGuild including the following:

```
Client.GetGuild(GuildId);
Client.Guilds.FirstOrDefault();
```

However it always returns null. I know that in Discord.js you need to use a fetch guild method for the cache but I can't find an equivalent method in Discord.Net. Can anyone help?

Comment: Where are you doing this? The only reason Guilds should be empty is if the client hasn't fully downloaded all the guild data. You shouldn't try accessing any sort of Guild data before the ready event fires.

Comment: @Anu6is this is called directly after `await Client.LoginAsync(TokenType.Bot, token);` and `await Client.StartAsync();` so the client should definitely be ready by this point

Comment: Right, so like I said, it's simply a matter of timing. Directly after Login means that the the guild data is still being downloaded. You need to wait for the ready event.

Answer (score 0):

Thought I'd answer this after finding the solution, to build onto @Anu6is's comment. Sadly `await _client.StartAsync();` doesn't wait until all the data has been fully loaded.

It's better to handle code that gets data from the client only after the `ready` event has been fired.
You can do this by adding the following in your `public async Task MainAsync()` function.

```
_client.Ready += ReadyAsync;
```

and then adding a function to your Program class called `ReadyAsync` like so:

```
private async Task ReadyAsync()
{
    //--- Handle client data here
}
```

Here's a full working example:

```
public class Program
{
    private DiscordSocketClient _client;
    public static Task Main(string[] args) => new Program().MainAsync();

    public async Task MainAsync()
    {
        var config = new DiscordSocketConfig()
        {
            GatewayIntents = GatewayIntents.AllUnprivileged | GatewayIntents.MessageContent | GatewayIntents.Guilds | GatewayIntents.GuildMembers,
            
        };
        _client = new DiscordSocketClient(config);
        _client.Log += Log;
        _client.Ready += ReadyAsync;
        _client.MessageReceived += MessageReceivedAsync;

        var token = "YOUR_TOKEN";

        await _client.LoginAsync(TokenType.Bot, token);
        await _client.StartAsync();
        // Block this task until the program is closed.
        await Task.Delay(-1);
    }

    private Task Log(LogMessage msg)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(msg.ToString());
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private Task getAllGuildChannels()
    {
        var guilds = _client.Guilds; // This will list all the guilds the bot is connected to
        var channels = _client.GetGuild(SOME_CHANNEL_ID)?.Channels;
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private async Task MessageReceivedAsync(SocketMessage message)
    {
        if (message.Content.ToLower() == "hello")
        {
            await message.Channel.SendMessageAsync("Hello, Discord!");
        }
    }

    private async Task ReadyAsync()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("================ BOT CONNECTED ================");
        await getAllGuildChannels();

    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Searched the [docs](https://discordnet.dev/api/Discord.IDiscordClient.html), here it is [documentation ss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tqjgK.jpg)

It's `GetGuildsAsync`

Comment: This does the exact same thing as `GetGuild()` except for it's asynchronous. It still returns an empty list. Also weirdly it can only be called if you cast your SocketClient as a IDiscordClient like so `(Client as IDiscordClient).GetGuildsAsync()` so maybe I am doing something wrong

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).